# function shExpMatch always returns FALSE in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, proxy

What's wrong ? telenet.be is a domain with sites like mijn.telenet.be which should also be forwarded to proxy.

```
if (shExpMatch(url, "telenet.be"))
{
 alert("urlwaarde=");
 alert(url);
 return "PROXY webproxy:8080";
}
```

There is not an else part yet. Maybe some guys can help me building up a nice pac file.

Comment: 1. What's a pac file? 2. What the shExpMatch function is supposed to do? Are you sure it is supposed to work on IE 10?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go

```
if (shExpMatch(url, "telenet.be") || shExpMatch(url, "*.telenet.be"))
{
 alert("urlwaarde=");
 alert(url);
 return "PROXY webproxy:8080";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this MS support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274204/en-us) shExpMatch only accepts "shell expressions" which only support "?" and "*"... so @booya is right in you having to try "*.telenet.be" in stead of just "telenet.be".

If you really need full blown regular expressions you can go the javascript way:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    // For instance, if the server has 4 alphabetic characters, 
    // such as "MSDN", route it through a specific proxy: 

    var regexpr = /[a-zA-Z]{4}.microsoft.com/;
    if(regexpr.test(host))
        return "PROXY w3proxy:8080; DIRECT";

    // Or else connect directly:
    return "DIRECT";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution that worked for me was like this:
if (shExpMatch(host, "telenet.be"))